# Proposal for a redesign of the `ask` form

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, quality-improvement

## Context

This post suggests some changes to the question asking form (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in order to improve question quality.

## Problems and suggestions

We have an [extensive guide on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately most newcomers have never read that page and I honestly can't blame them: It's a wall of text hidden behind a text link. Many of the points mentioned there are not reflected in the associated question asking form at all, anyways.

### 1. Re-layout the title field

For example, the title bar appears as the first input field on the form but the guide tells you to

> write the title last

### 2. Change the title placeholder text

The help mentions how a good title looks like and all examples start with a [question word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word). However, the form says

> What's your programming question? Be specific.

While this makes the purpose of the site clear (programming questions), it fails in telling the user how to choose a good title. [All top-voted questions on SO](http://All%20top-voted%20questions%20on%20SO) are starting with a question word. People are great at learning by copying, so how about showing a random good title in the placeholder?

### 3. Emphasise the code inclusion button

The help also mentions to

> Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem

But on the form page the code inclusion is hidden in the formatting bar. Judging from the many first questions I've seen, many people do not include or do not format their code at all. Contrary to web links, quotes or bullet lists (other tools from the editor bar), I think almost every question on StackOverflow should contain a code example. How about we put that code sample button next to the `Post Your Question` button or somewhere else just more prominent? If the tags contain CSS, JS or HTML also emphasise a button to the extended runnable code snippet editor. Runnable samples are worth gold!

### 4. Make the question text area bigger

Most questions are lacking context and even without looking into the statistics, I bet the most popular reason for closing questions is "Unclear what you're asking". Have you ever wondered why shopping carts are always so big? It's so you feel obliged to fill it. We should do the same with the text area for questions. Resizing it from Twitter-size to Blogger-size offers the users a better understanding of the expectations for a problem description.

### 5. Offer multiple text areas

This is a follow-up on the last point. The guide isn't very specific on this other than telling you to `Introduce the problem`.

Whenever working through the queues or commenting new questions, my most often used comments are

> What have you tried so far?

and

> What exactly is the problem?

Therefore I would like to suggest splitting the text area into the following parts:

1. Context: What are you trying to do?
2. What have you tried so far?
3. What exactly isn't working?

## Summary of suggestions / Mockup

I've thrown together some of the suggestions above into this rough mock-up. I am not a designer, so please bear with me.

[image: Suggested question form]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions

Comment: loosely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Answer (score 3):

There does need to be a redesign of the ask question interface. However, I don't think that asking "What have you tried?" or just moving one input from one place to another is going to make much of a difference.

There needs to be some degree of actual overhaul here. Perhaps the word restoration is in order, considering that the interface was built 9 years ago and has seen quite a lot of weather.

The ask question page is the first step. Every question started there, and so it needs to get some attention. I know that the team is "currently working" on this interface (or at least that is what I keep hearing) so at least it seems to be a priority.

As far as improvements, they need to be significant. Perhaps as an optional wizard. Perhaps in a new set of features in the interface such as [tag inclusion in the automated search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280668/include-the-chosen-tags-in-the-search-criteria-for-questions-that-may-already-h), or perhaps an entrance to a mentor queue, or something else great with waffles and unicorns.

So I do agree that the ask question interface needs to be redesigned, I just don't think that this approach outlined really goes far enough, and there have also been several issues with "what have you tried", or similar phrases, in the past (for example, users asking that without actually investing in the response or spending the time to ask what prompted *them* to ask for an attempt).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. While I agree that the additional text areas are debatable, I am not sure what is bad about making small improvements while waiting for bigger ones. A re-layout takes less than one day of work and brings instant effect. Betting on big changes only is 100% waterfall model and that has proven to be not quite the right thing for targeting user needs.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is a *very* large site. There are millions of users. Any change to something as central as the ask question page will require a suite of testing to see its effect. That is a lot of effort to waste on making minimalistic changes, especially if they do not have any impact. The linked duplicate contains many improvements, and it does make sense to provide a substantial improvement considering the amount of work that goes into testing what the overall feature impact is.

Comment: "especially if they do not have any impact" well, you can't know until you have tried. Sometimes small changes can have unexpectedly big impact. The rest of your comment reads like "we do waterfall because we want to test once only". You might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development. Especially the parts "adaptive planning, evolutionary development, early delivery, and continuous improvement"

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak - You seem to be suffering from an issue with identifying design approaches with the real world. You can know many things without trying when the outcome is obvious. To be clear, the feature suggested here stands absolutely no chance of moving forward, lacks research, and does not solve any identified problems.