# Recognise "Not Working" and suggest improvement to user

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

I frequently find the words 'not working' in a post mean that a user has not explained exactly how it is not working.

For example, most recently here:

[New to SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25762106)

Can we identify "not working" and "doesn't work" etc. and automatically hint the user to provide more info?

It's not possible to ascertain whether they have provided info in addition to "not working", but highly reliable anecdotal analysis indicates they don't.

I'm sure you guys have thought of this and extended it but when I search "doesn't work" on Meta, I see a lot of questions saying, "Blah blah doesn't work!"

I think we can agree this definition will give a lot of false negatives. Many good questions might also have "doesn't work" in them. Is there any way to actually get some real metrics in this though?

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252327/how-to-figure-out-if-a-so-question-is-viable-prior-to-posting

Comment: If you can come up with a regex that has a low percentage of false positives.... I'm only joking. Meta.se has a complete tag on [quality-filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quality-filter)

Comment: +1 Detect, and block submission with the message "We understand your code is "not working", however we require you *demonstrate with examples* what you have tried, what the result was, and why this doesn't meet your requirements.  Asshole."  With or without the name calling.

Comment: I don't think they're being an Asshole. Just a Lazy Turd.

Comment: I think that whenever someone types "not working" in a question title, the page should show a screen sized rubber duck (with some translucent, gray overlay over everything else), and clicking on said duck should take the user to Jeff's Atwood post in his blog about rubber duck problem solving.

Comment: Sometimes people use "not working" as a starter to explain what exactly is not working, what have they tried and their investigation. Does this mean that they have to change their writing style just because some other users are not nicely explaining their problems? It is like ignoring all people who start conversation with "I am sorry" just because some homeless people use it in "I am sorry, can you give me some cash?"

Comment: I think you can't filter questions like this, since this phrase is also used in good questions. I think you can mainly filter by phrases that are only used in bad questions, or need to be accompanied by a specific other phrase to form a good question. Otherwise you might as well give a warning everytime in the form of "Over 90% of the questions on SO is bad, so yours is likely to be bad as well. Please improve your question". But that will raise some eyebrows, I think. :)

Comment: At least title should not contain 'not working'. Most of the time I edit the question's title after reading the question.I hate title contains 'does not work' which does not give me any idea what will be the post until I read it.I also want this feature to apply.

Answer (score 45):

> It's not possible to ascertain whether they have provided info in addition to not working but highly reliable anecdotal analysis indicates they don't ;)

Aye, but this is the rub.

Your anecdotal evidence is just a reflection of the fact that the majority of new questions on Stack Overflow are utterly abysmal crap that should have never gotten posted in the first place. The issues run far wider and deeper than the lack of description about what "not working" means.

A well-written question will often say something like

> I have written the following code [snippet], but it is not working. Instead of dividing the two variables, it throws a `DivideByZeroException`. What does that mean? I have tried doing [*x*], but the compiler formatted my hard drive. How can I fix this code so that it will compile?

Your filter would block that because I said "not working". Oops.

To put it another way, in good writing, you generally start by telling someone what you are going to tell them, like a preview or a summary. You'd start out by making the claim that the code is not working, then you'd go on to expand on that, explaining why it is not working. If you block any question that does that, you're guaranteed a bunch of false positives.

Of course, I'm not against filtering new questions in principle. [On the contrary, I am very much in favor of that.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter) I just think there are better heuristics that we can use. The heuristics used by the "low quality" posts queue are apparently pretty good—I see very few false positives in there. You'd need to take multiple factors into account: length, spelling, punctuation, the presence of code snippets, etc. etc.

One thing we *could* do, though, is provide just-in-time help. This has been suggested before, many times. I'm too lazy to hunt down the links now, but a few minutes of searching on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ should help—start with the query "clippy". One of the triggers for the just-in-time help could be the phrase "not working". Something distinctly non-paperclip-like would appear in the right-hand margin of the question editor screen and remind you to include a *complete description* of the problem, blah blah. Probably linking to [the MVCE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

People who know how to ask a good question could ignore it. And so would the people who don't care about writing a good question. But you might get lucky and catch that 1% of conscientious askers.

Comment: *the compiler formatted my hard drive* made me giggle hard enough that my boss took my sugar supply off my desk

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's much easier to find 'not working' than identify it's opposite. Perhaps there is no automated solution to this and I need to just continue posting a brusqe comment and suggesting the questions closure.

Comment: @James Hey, at least [demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) didn't fly out of your nose.

Comment: This post is surprisingly critical and well-spoken. It deserves a bounty.

Comment: This post is emblematic of the unfortunately all-too-common logical error of saying "Solution A [is bad/is inadvisable/should not be implemented] because (interpreted narrowly as proposed) it won't solve **every** case of problem B." Also, it fails to consider the obvious improvement of limiting the check to titles.