# Can we flag questions with insufficient information in a way that promotes improvement?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Although I'm tempted to suggest banning the phrase ["not working"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271089/recognise-not-working-and-suggest-improvement-to-user) it's obvious that this is not a solution to the problem of people asking questions that are ridiculously thin on details or otherwise fail to speak in terms specific enough to be answered.

People who post questions like "Help, my program isn't working" and fail to provide much more in the way of details are often new Stack Overflow visitors and they get severely punished with down votes or have their question almost immediately flagged for closing or deletion.

This can make the Stack Overflow crowd seem like a bunch of thugs that are quick to lay the smackdown on anyone who doesn't live up to our standards even when the goal is to try and maintain a level of quality both in questions and answers.

Instead of down-voting, could people be given an option to "recommend improvement" where a few things could be flagged from a list?

Giving people concrete goals like "Include a small sample of code to illustrate what you've done to try and solve the problem" or "Include the specific error message you're getting" should go a long way towards explaining what the problems are. Being able to flag one or more of these in a kind, encouraging way would help with first impressions.

Comment: You have 100k reputation, have been around for 7 years, yet have fewer than 1k downvotes. Maybe [tag:ruby] doesn't have that much garbage. Or maybe you've misunderstood what a downvote is, because it certainly isn't punishment.

Comment: I've been around long enough to know how the voting system works, but just because I understand doesn't mean I have to agree that it's the best possible way of handling these sorts of grievances. I save my down-votes for harmful answers. I usually flag to close anything that doesn't fit.

Comment: I don't want to spend any more effort on questions than the poster has.  Code dumps with 'Help, my program isn't working', no decent formatting/indentation, no test files/inputs, no resulting outputs, no error-messages, no details of debugging done etc. get down and close voted, that's it.  'are often new Stack Overflow visitors. meh. The posters would not even consider treating their doctor/lawyer/accountant/garage tech. in such a manner because repect, (and the punishing bills that would ensue), and SO contributors should be given the same level of respect, if not more, for free help.

Comment: If you want to see what happens when 'improvement advice' is given, see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088566/creation-of-two-linked-list-using-menu-driven-program  The OP obstinately refuses to do the simple job of formatting/indenting its code to make it readable, despite the fact tht the poor indents hide a serious bug.  Refuses over, and over, and over again.  It's a waste of time spending anything except the very minimum effort on these type of questions - if you do, you will end up totally frustrated and depressed by these users.  No good deed goes unpunished on SO.

Comment: One, common, reason why such questions are posted is that the OP would rather spend time in a bar than doing their own homework, after all, why bother if some SO drone will do it all for you? One reason why OP's refuse to supply extra info, indentation ec. when asked is that they don't have it and have no way of getting it: they have no compiler etc. and are completely clueless since they are being paid for doing someone else's homework.  Forget it, it might seem like a good idea on the face of it, but every drop of blood you have will be sucked out in a week.

Answer (score 12):

> Instead of down-voting, could people be given an option to "recommend improvement" where a few things could be flagged from a list?
>
> Giving people concrete goals like "Include a small sample of code to illustrate what you've done to try and solve the problem" or "Include the specific error message you're getting" should go a long way towards explaining what the problems are.

You've literally just described closing and downvoting.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: It literally feels absolutely awful for new people to the site to be subjected to that as their first interaction. If you want to push people away, this is a good way to do it.

Comment: @tadman forget sites/software.  Would you treat any other professional body in such a manner?  Would you dump your car outside your garage with a note 'Doesn't go right, fix it'?   It feels absolutely awful when highly-skilled and experienced engineers are just dumped on in a cavalier, 'You can't charge me, so just go fix my stuff now!', manner:(

Comment: @tadman People don't like being told that their questions aren't good questions, and that they need to fix them in order to get an answer.  They're upset at the inherent fact that they're being told that they need to actually do work to get their problem solved.  You're complaining about the implications **of your own suggestion**.

Comment: @MartinJames The problem I have with the current system is you must choose one option, there's no way of ticking off multiple *specific* problems. Presenting this as a list of "to do" things would be a lot better than a blanket rejection with a laundry list of things that may or may not apply.

Comment: @tadman If you feel like you need to add additional clarification, you're free to do so in comments.

Comment: @Servy I just feel like there's some very common complaints that require saying the same thing over and over and over again. Instead of "pick one which loosely applies" a case of "pick all that apply" would be better. Surely this would make the job of the moderators easier.

Answer (score 5):

OK, this is easily fixed:)

Please provide an email address so that links to such questions can be easily forwarded to yourself.  You can then suggest improvements to the posters.

I think that it's extremely laudable of you to help out in such a manner though, to be honest, I did not think that you could type that fast and work 24/7.

It's nice to find out that not all SO contributors are elitist. hostile mob downvoters that don't punish all those grossly inadequate and insulting questions with down votes or immediately flag them for closing or deletion.

Maybe SO could help out here and provide a 'send question link to tadman' button?

Comment: I'm not asking for a firehose feed of crappy questions, I'm asking for the "Flag for review" process to have the ability to select "Check all that apply" instead of having to pick one of several usually inadequate options.