# Don't post low-quality questions or answers. Make users fix them instead

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts

### Scenario 1:

An automatic gatekeeper would detect and intercept all Low Quality questions and answers.

Currently, an algorithm detects Low Quality posts and puts them into a review queue. My proposal is to apply this algorithm at an earlier stage, *before* anything is posted.

Then the gatekeeper would prompt users to do some editing:

> "You must edit and improve this before we can post it.
>
> Here's how to write a good question/answer..." (etc.)

Then the user can edit/resubmit, and it will be posted if it's sufficiently improved.

But if it's still Low Quality, it is **not posted.**

This "preemptive auto-reviewer" could be a standalone feature, for all users, or part of the [Wizard for new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard).

### Scenario 2:

Status quo. Moderators and Low Quality queue reviewers get annoyed as they downvote, criticize, flag, review, and delete answers.

Users get angry and frustrated seeing their posts downvoted, criticized, and deleted. And they will probably blame the site and moderators/reviewers, not themselves.

### Related Questions & Answers

- [Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting)
- [How to figure out if a SO question is viable prior to posting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252327/how-to-figure-out-if-a-so-question-is-viable-prior-to-posting)
- [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions)
- [New users need better awareness of what is expected of them when they ask their first question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/292482)

### Summary

Personally, I like the gatekeeper idea better. What do you think?

Comment: The posts In the low quality queue are also eventually humanly reviewed. We already see users finding trivial ways to go against the algorithm (I mean we've all seen 'adding text here so SO lets me post' in questions, no?).... How will that gatekeeper be any different?

Comment: @Patrice (1) New users often mean well, but don't know what a "good question for SO" is. This would teach them how to post. (2) If they ignore the advice and find a way to post anyway, and it's deleted during review, they can't say they weren't warned. And if they add text such as `adding text here`, it will attract attention and get deleted more quickly. (3) Or the users might give up and not post a Low Quality or off-topic question.

Comment: In my experience, users often improve their own low-quality posts in response to polite and helpful advice from commenters. My idea is to move that to an earlier stage of the process, before anything is posted.

Comment: So, the way I see it, it's another human review queue, where the intent is to teach users (which already happens organically when people comment)... I don't see this being an improvement over the current status quo.  Also you seem to conflate a lot of things in your post. You talking about answers or questions? Your title says answers, but here you say questions...

Comment: @Patrice The automated gatekeeper would require higher-quality posts upfront, before posting, so that human reviewers would have fewer Low Quality posts to deal with later. And yes, this proposal applies to both questions and answers -- I will edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: We don't need to create a new algorithm. We already have a Low Quality detection algorithm, we're using it, and we should just be using it earlier.

Comment: But.... We do. Right now the 'low quality' detection is easily circumventable without making the question any good. If you use that algorithm, people will eventually learn how to trick it into letting bad content pass. Then we are back to square 1, with just an added difficulty for the users who want to learn our ways. If you want this proposal to fly, I personally feel the accuracy of the algorithm to detect these is super important.

Comment: Arguing about quality of the post with people may at the end lead to better post... I don't see how trying to convince automated script would be any positive experience at current level of automated quality detection (maybe in 6-8 weeks when AI is better :) ).

Comment: @Patrice Are we currently using a "low quality detection" algorithm to filter things out before a user posts them? If so, it's apparently a more permissive algorithm than the one that finds posted questions/answers for the Low Quality queue. In my opinion we should do more filtering upfront.

Comment: You want to deter people posting bad content. Right now the algorithm that puts questions in the queue can easily be circumvented with crap questions. By making it a barrier to entry, some users will, wrongfully of course, feel forced to add crap on their questions. You're not teaching anyone. You're making a barrier that even good intentioned people might trip into, then get confused about. If you think we are getting too much drama for being 'unwelcoming' and elitist now.... Imagine after this goes through.

Comment: @Patrice One problem is, people especially new users don't realize what "bad content" is, what should be in a question, what is on-topic, etc. We can tell them about that before accepting their post -- which for many of them is their first post -- or else allow them to post it and then knock them down.

Comment: As well as people getting around the LQ queue, there are also posts that just don't make it there in the first place, and ones that are added erroneously.

Comment: @jkdev We do show them stackoverflow.com/ask/advice before they're allowed to post, and if the post is not acceptable (too much code, etc.) they're not accepted. About the "Here's how to write a good question/answer..." part, they're always shown on the right pane.

Comment: @jkdev indeed new users don't understand that. The solution is to teach and educate. Not to build a mindless barrier that doesn't help educate. Again, if we can build a real machine learning process and *truly* filter out bad questions, sure. The fact that a lot of bad content doesn't end up in the Triage queue and that some good content gets there, shows to me that the algorithm we have now isn't enough. It'll block good questions and have users scratch their heads as to why, and it'll still allow a ton of bad content to go through.

Comment: @Patrice You're right, the education is the important part. "Here's how to write a good question/answer..." would be educational. That's why I recommended we include it. The tough part is making sure people see, read and understand it before they post. As for the right-hand panel with small text, my guess is that few or no users read it (even I didn't notice it for a long time!) We've got to put that kind of thing front and center, and don't allow posting unless people show they understand the requirements.

Comment: Another idea... create a MOOC about "How to use Stack Overflow" and give free admission to all new users who submit low-quality posts? (I might create a new additional Meta question with this proposal.)

Comment: but again, right now the algorithm is often wrong. Both good cases get flagged as bad, and vice versa. You need to fix that before you can use that algorithm to bar entry to the site

Answer (score 4):

The Triage queue [was created for this very purpose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage): it gets question that an automated system caught as borderline low-quality and acts as both a sorting and improvement forge and feedback for the automated system.